# nginx multiple ports for reverse proxies

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I had nginx to use reverse proxying to lookup a node.js app - essentially I was listening on port 80 and servering the node.js content running on port 3000.

Now, on the same domain, for the same nginx instance I'd like to setup another reverse proxy, but my configuration doesn't seem to work.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name test2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

as you can see, I'd still like to have the port 80 -> 3000 reversing, but additionally I'd like to add 8080 -> 3001 to the mix. Any suggestions please?

Comment: The configuration seems ok, but is test = test2? you said that they are the same domain in your question.

Comment: yes it's the same domain. if the server_name is test for both, that doesn't seem to work either. If I remove the 8080 port section, everything works happily and merrily.

Comment: what happens when you browse the `8080` URL if you have both servers set, do you get a server not found error, or do you get something like a `500 error code` ?

Comment: can you verify that nginx actually binds with the port `8080` after you reload the new settings

Comment: would I do that by executing 'netstat -tlpn' and look for 8080?

Comment: yea, run it with `sudo` to see program names too